# Count number of pages in History

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

IS there is any way to check how many pages are present in Dom/cache?

In my application there are several pages, If any time suppose session expires then server gives me response code say-1. I check response code every time and if it is -1, Then I have to show index page to user for that I am doing this:

```
window.history.go(-4);
```

But in above case I had given value as -4 because here I know that there are 4 pages in Dom, But at runtime Ihow I came to know how many pages are present in DOm?

Any help/suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use window.location to redirect to index page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
 window.history.length //4
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.history

> length    Integer Read-only. Returns the number of elements in the
>   session history, including the currently loaded page. For example, for
>   a page loaded in a new tab this property returns 1.

Comment: Will this really work if the user didn't start on the index-page?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `window.location` instead, but if you really want to count the number of pages in the DOM you can simply do: `$('[data-role="page"]').length`.